# Mysql запрос выборка за текущий месяц

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

помогите составить запрос на выборку из таблицы за текущий месяц, дату храню в unixtime

```
"SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE `id` = :profile_id ORDER BY `time` DESC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите [код тут(в правой колонке)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc5ae/1), там есть два варианта, второй хоть и больше но надежней.